# ASP.Net MVC Tracing Shows 75 seconds I can't account for

Tags: asp.net, performance, trace

I noticed long render times for a page with a user's account on one of my company's websites. I turned tracing on locally and accessed his account from my development machine, and it as 75 seconds of rendering that I can't find. I added tracing through both the master and child `aspx` files, but even after the last bit of code (a foreach) in the child page is called, there is another 75 seconds of something happening.

Trace results.

Half a second makes sense (cleaning up something, I don't know what), but 75 makes NO sense.

[image: Trace Results]

Comment: Might be something to do with database connectivity, have you checked that its not waiting for a lock? In this transaction is there any DB activity, if so can you run SQL profiler and see all connections and whats being run in the course of this web request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you realy have some code in the views that takes some time, but the 76 seconds might be spent by ASP.NET MVC rendering itself.

This can happen when you have a couple Html helpers (typically action links) that use routing and you have a good amount of entries in the routing table. Try to render the page with most of the helpers removed to check if this is the case.

Comment: It didn't solve the entire issue, but that was about 5 seconds (or possibly just a margin of error). I have found that IQueryable was causing the bottom foreach to "finshis" before it was actually done, and when I cleaned up the query and moved it from Linq2Sql to actual SQL, that cleared the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've closed every object you've instantiated that has an IDisposable interface.